# pygame won't play sound on raspberry pi zero

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame

```
import time
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/Desktop/sound.wav")

sound.play()
time.sleep(10)
```

This is the code i'm currently working with. For some reason the sound will not play. I am using a bluetooth speaker to play the sound through. I'm not sure if I need to change the channel through the code some way but the normal sound the Raspberry Pi makes is set to the bluetooth by default. When I play the sound file it plays normally but when using the code it will not. It may be useful to know that I have gotten similar code to work with other programs on other raspberry pis but for some reason this particular instance is not working. I am using a raspberry pi zero w. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating dependencies

```
sudo apt update && apt upgrade && apt dist-upgrade
```

Else this:

```
import time
import pygame

channelA = pygame.mixer.Channel(1)
sounda = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/Desktop/sound.wav")
channelA.set_volume(1.0)
channelA.play(sounda)
```

Comment: Unfortunately updating things did not fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long. I just tested this and nothing played. There was no error when running the program; it just didn't play any sound.